# Change color of v-chip on click

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm wanting to change the color of the chip when I click on the chip itself and change it back when clicked again.

So far I have not been able to achieve that. I know that `:color` can be used to dynamically change the color initially, but not sure after the click.

I have an array to store the selected values.

```js
data () {
   return {
     restrictions = ['Restriction 1','Restriction 2','Restriction 3','Restriction 4'],
     selectedRestrictions = []
   }
},
methods(){
  handleChipColor(){
    return 'primary';
  },
  selectRestriction(restriction){
      const el = this.selectedRestrictions.findIndex(el => el === restriction);
      el < 0 ? this.selectedRestrictions.push(restriction) :    this.selectedRestrictions.splice(el,1);
    }
  }
```

```html
<v-chip class="margin" :color="handleChipColor" v-for="restriction in restrictions"  @click="selectRestriction(restriction)" :key="restriction">{{restriction}}</v-chip>
```

I'm able to manipulate the array to have the colors of the chips selected, I'm just not 100% sure how to update the colors on the chips.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

binding the condition directly to the color prop should do it for example try this:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      restrictions: ['Restriction 1', 'Restriction 2', 'Restriction 3', 'Restriction 4'],
      selectedRestrictions: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectRestriction(restriction) {
      const el = this.selectedRestrictions.findIndex(el => el === restriction);
      el < 0 ? this.selectedRestrictions.push(restriction) : this.selectedRestrictions.splice(el, 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-chip-group>
      <v-chip v-for="(item, i) in restrictions" :color="selectedRestrictions.includes(item) ? 'error' : 'primary'" @click="selectRestriction(item)" :key="i">{{item}}</v-chip>
    </v-chip-group>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

you can also wrap the condition in a method and then bind the method to the color prop like this:

```
handleColor(item) {
  return this.selectedRestrictions.includes(item) ? 'error' : 'primary';
}
```

template:

```
<v-chip v-for="(item, i) in restrictions" :color="handleColor(item)" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized all I needed to do is check the array on the function call for the `:color` attribute.

```js
checkIfRestrictionSelected(restriction){
   // Pick the two colors to alternate 
   return this.selectedRestrictions.find(el => el === restriction) ? 'primary' : 'secondary';
}
```

```html
<v-chip class="margin" :color="checkIfRestrictionSelected(restriction)" @click="selectRestriction(restriction)" v-for="restriction in restrictions" :key="restriction">{{restriction}}</v-chip>
```

Comment: You could also simply have

`return this.selectedRestrictions.includes(restriction) ? 'primary' : 'secondary';`

Comment: I realized that from the previous answer. Thanks!